# How do I publish exactly one message?

Tags: ros, roscpp, message, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have been working with ROS for sometime now, and quite happily. However, there is one sticky issue that I would like to resolve. I learnt the basics of publishing from the tutorial "Writing a simple publisher and subscriber". This is the gist of what is demonstrated:

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);

ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

int count = 0;

while (ros::ok())
{

  std_msgs::String msg;

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "hello world " << count;
  msg.data = ss.str();
  chatter_pub.publish(msg);
  ros::spinOnce();
  loop_rate.sleep();
  ++count;
}
```

I have been using the same format for publishing ever since. Obviously, this will keep publishing as long as the program terminates or roscore terminates. I would like to publish a single message, irrespective of message size. In this case, I would like publish one std_msgs::String message. How do I do that?

(Nov 14, 2012)
Upon reading comments from Benoit Larochelle and Lorenz, I would like to make my question more specific. In my case, latched topics does not apply to the current application logic. I would like all current subscribers to get the message but not future subscribers. Also, the subscribers are external packages that listen to standard non-stamped messages. In addition, I cannot use actionlib since the subscribers do not use it as well. One example is to send a twist command (that does not have a timestamp) to a swarm of robots simultaneously. We ofcourse dont want future subscribers to react to an old command (latched) and we do not want to send the command at a specific rate, but only send it once.

I have tried simple removing the while loop and executing "publish" and "spinOnce()" just one time. This doesn't work, no messages are published.

Can anyone tell me how I can publish a single message?

Thanks
Shanker Keshavdas
DFKI, Saarbruecken, Germany

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11167/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message?/) by [Shanker](https://answers.ros.org/users/156/shanker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
I don't think topics were supposed to be used that way. I think there might be hacks possible, e.g. by using subscription callbacks and publish only to a selected set of subscribers. But I doubt that a really robust implementation is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your case, I guess the problem is that ROS needs some time to register at the core and to establish all subscriber connections. When you just publish one single message, chances are good that it gets lost because the subscriber is not connected yet. A quick fix would be to add a sleep right after creation of the publisher.

If you really want to make sure that clients are connected, you can use the version of advertise which takes one parameter of type `AdvertiseOptions` [see here](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a68232c46583059c8f7d948b154689e4c).
In `AdvertiseOptions`, you can set a connect callback that gets called whenever a subscriber connects.

Another possiblility is to use the method `getNumSubscribers` of the `Publisher` class returned by the advertise call. Just wait for at least one subscriber. You can do something like:

```
ros::Rate poll_rate(100);
while(chatter_pub.getNumSubscribers() == 0)
    poll_rate.sleep();
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-17**:
Latching the topic will also help if the subscriber is coming up and down, see the answer from @Martin Günther

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-12**:
Has this been fixed in Fuerte? I.e., am I guaranteed that my subscribers will get my message when I publish it (assuming no loss due to the network)?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
There never was anything to fix. As soon as the connection is established, messages are guaranteed to arrive given there are no buffer overruns. And how should a publisher know that a subscriber will connect in the future. To resent the last message, you can latch though.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-12**:
Ok, maybe I did not understand your answer correctly. You say "chances are good that it gets lost". Why is ROS relying on chance? Could it happen that a message gets published before the connection gets established? For example, if a publisher is created and starts publishing immediately?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
ROS is not relying on chances. But how should a publisher know for which subscribers to wait before publishing? When a subscriber connects, it first needs to query the core for all publishers and then connect to each of them. This takes time and messages are only received after the connection is up.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-12**:
Ok, this is clear, but I don't understand why we're discussing future subscribers. The problem described by Shanker is that the node shutdown right after publishing a single message, and any node that was already listening on that topic did not receive the message. Do we still have to sleep after?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
It's still the same problem, the publisher doesn't know about the subscribers yet. When a publisher comes up, the subscribers get a notification to connect to it. This takes time. The publisher might have sent its message and terminated before any subscriber had a chance to connect.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-12**:
Ok, so how can I ensure that my message will get to all current subscribers? Do I have to get the # of subscribers and count the calls to connect_cb? And then only when they are all connected do I call publish? Or maybe this is already done internally by ROS? Or is there an easier way?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
My answer suggested to wait for more than zero subscribers. If you know how many subscribers you assume, you can wait. That's not the nicest, cleanest or most robust way though. If you have a node that keeps running, I suggest to use a latched topic.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-12**:
Ok, that's what I meant by "guaranteed". Assuming a situation where I have 0-N subscribers and I don't want to latch due to the system logic (old messages are useless), then it's not so nice like you say. As a suggestion, the publisher could handle this before actually firing the message

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
How could a publisher handle this? It cannot send messages to subscribers it doesn't know about neither can it wait for them (since it doesn't know about the subscribers).

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
I'll explain it in a new solution because I do not have enough characters here.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to what @Lorenz said, [latching the connection](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#line-53) might be useful. Also, I'm not sure what happens when your node exits right after sending the message, so waiting for some time (or for some subscribers) might be needed even when using latched connections.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-13**:
Indeed, you will want to latch the value.  ROS is like live streaming video -- if you miss the start of the game, you miss it (though you can get the last-published value if you latch).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your answers.

I was successful in using latch and getNumSubscribers() to achieve a single message publisher, as explained above.

I would like to point out that using 'rostopic echo' command to verify a single message publisher has not been successful for me. When I run 'rostopic echo', I notice that an additional subscriber is listed under 'rostopic info'. Thus I assumed it would behave like a regular subscriber.

I observe that when I use a separate program to subscribe to the topic, I receive the message successfully. However, 'rostopic echo' does not display the single message that I am trying to publish.

Here is some demo code with the relevant portions:

// Code starts here

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "VirtualObjectPublisher");

ros::NodeHandle VirtualObjectNode("~");

ros::Publisher VirtualObjectROSPublisher;

ros::Rate poll_rate(100);

bool latchOn = 1;

/* Some processing */

VirtualObjectROSPublisher = VirtualObjectNode.advertise<eu_nifti_env_msg_ros::ElementOfInterestMessage>("/eoi", 20, latchOn);

 while(VirtualObjectROSPublisher.getNumSubscribers()==0)
{
   ROS_ERROR("Waiting for subscibers");
   sleep(10);
}
ROS_ERROR("Got subscriber");
VirtualObjectROSPublisher.publish(publishEOImsg);
ros::spinOnce();

 while(ros::ok())
{
   sleep(3);    
}

return 0;
```

}

// I added the ROS_ERROR for debugging. The same with the sleep statements. I also added the final ros::ok(), loop since I didn't want the node to be destroyed prematurely, to better understand the problem.

My test procedure:

i. Terminal 1 : Start the above code

ii. After 3 seconds, Terminal 2 : 'rostopic echo /eoi'.

iii. Terminal 1 :

[ERROR] [1318328446.461543684]: Waiting for subscibers

[ERROR] [1318328456.461746879]: Waiting for subscibers

[ERROR] [1318328466.461960429]: Got subscriber

Terminal 2 does not echo the topic.

However, as I explained earlier, if I have a program with a Subscriber, it reads the message successfully.

Regards,

Shanker Keshavdas

---

Originally posted by [Shanker](https://answers.ros.org/users/156/shanker/) with karma: 259 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-10-11**:
Please edit your question if you want to add more info instead of answering it. This is a little unusual if you're used to forums, but it keeps the thread tidy.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the comments from Lorenz, the problem seems to be that the publisher is too fast; that is, it publishes before the subscriber has opened a direct connection to the publisher. Therefore, the goal is to make the publisher "wait" until all subscribers have established a connection. I don't think that the problem stems from closing the publisher too soon.

Here is an idea that I have not tested, but that should work with multiple subscribers. It is not 100% robust, but assuming that no subscribers comes or leaves exactly when the publisher is launched, it should not have problems.

EDIT: This method would not work because a functionality that I expected available from ROS does not seem to be there. See comments in the code.

```
int numSubscribersConnected = 0;

void connectCallback(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher& pub)
{
    numSubscribersConnected++;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "MyPublisher");

    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");

    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<foo::MyMessage>("/myTopic", 100, connectCallback);

    ros::Rate poll_rate(100);

    ros::Time maxTime(ros::Time::now()+1000); // Will wait at most 1000 ms

    // This is wrong. It returns only the number of subscribers that have already established their direct connections to this publisher
    //int numExistingSubscribers = pub.getNumSubscribers();

    // This method does not exist, as far as I know. In the comments below, I suggested having a similar functionality. This method would return the number of total subscribers to this topic over the ROS network
    int numExistingSubscribers = ros::getNumSubscribers("/myTopic");

    while(numExistingSubscribers!=numSubscribersConnected && ros::Time::now()<maxTime)
    {
        poll_rate.sleep();
    }

    // Now the publisher is ready

    foo::MyMessage msg;
    pub.publish(msg);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
Personally, I always thought that this was taken care of by ROS. In my opinion, a publisher is not ready until the publisher-subscriber connections are ready. I would suggest that advertise() take a ros::Time parameter to specify the max timeout, and with zero it would keep the current behavior.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
I don't think advertise should take a time parameter, this can easily be achieved by the user by adding sleep. ROS is designed to be independent of the number of publishers and subscribers. If you need something more reliable, consider using actionlib for instance.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
My suggested solution is independent of the number of publishers and subscribers (correct me if I'm wrong). It handles all cases between 0 and N publishers and subscribers. Would a more reliable behavior hinder ROS in any way?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
Well, you say 'until the publisher-subscriber-connections are ready'. A timeout does not imply anything like that. It's just not possible to know how many connections need to be ready to be sure everything is set up beforehand. The timeout can easily be implemented by the user as well if desired.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
Then I must understand pub.getNumSubscribers() wrong. I thought that it told me how many connections need to be ready to be sure everything is set up beforehand. What does it tell me exactly then if not that?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
getNumSubscribers() returns the number of subscribers with which a connection is established already. All will receive published messages. It should be basically the same as `numSubscribersConnected` in your example.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
Ooohhh, now I see. The documentation is not clear on that though. In that case, my solution would not work at all. What I would then suggest for ROS is to have something like a centralized TopicManager (at the core), with a method `getNumSubscribers(std::string& topicName)`

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
That just shifts the problem. The rpc call to the core is probably slower than the connection negotiation. Really, if you need a reliable connection, either implement the sleep yourself, use actionlib, use latched topics or publish data at a specific rate.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
But the RPC call is already done. Line 403 of topic_manager.cpp: master::execute("registerPublisher", args, result, payload, true);. However, result is ignored. If it contained the # subscribers that have to subscribe, I think that it would solve the problem.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
True. You are right that it would be possible to find out how many nodes subscribed already. I have to admit that I didn't get what you meant in the first place. However, waiting for all subscribers would make the system less robust. The master can be out of sync if subscribers didn't die cleanly.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
Yes, you're right with the syncing issues. My suggestion is not fail-proof, but at least with a timeout option, we would increase the reliability when required and still allow not to wait (or not to wait too long) for other cases.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
I think the original use case for topics was a continuous data stream. That's how most parts of the ros system are designed and I actually never ran into a use case where such a behavior was necessary. It might be worth an enhancement ticket though.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-14**:
I found this similar ticket (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/2276), but I don't have a button "New Ticket" for ros (core), rather only for ros-pkg. Do I need to request permission to someone?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-14**:
You'll need an account at code.ros.org.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-14**:
I have one, and I filed tickets before for ros-pkg, but not for ros. I can go on https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ and browse the source and see the tickets, but I can't create one.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-14**:
Interesting. But I think roscpp is on github now anyway. Maybe you should file a ticket there. https://github.com/ros

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-14**:
You're right, the wiki is not up-to-date (it links to the old system). I created an account with Github and posted two tickets. Here they are for reference: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/21 and https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/22